# Does the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k \cdot |x-r_k|^\frac{1}{2}}$ coverges a.e?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

I dear friends. I have a question -

We take a count for the rationals in $[0,1]: Q \cap [0,1] = \uplus_{n=1}^{\infty} \{r_n\}$.

1) Does the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k \cdot |x-r_k|^\frac{1}{2}}$ coverges almost everywhere in $[0,1]$ with respect to the one-dimensional lebesgue measure $m$?

2) If so, is the sum, call it $S$,  is such that $S \in L^1([0,1])$?

3) Show (if $S$ exist almost everywhere) that $S \notin L^2(I)$, for every interval $I \subset [0,1]$ with $m(I) > 0$

Thank you so so much!
P.S

Hints are also welcome :)

Comment: *Hint.* (1) You can check that $\int_{0}^{1} S(x) \, dx < \infty$. (2) You can check that $S(x)^2 \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |x-r_n|^{-1}$ and this lower bound is not integrable on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Sangchul Lee note my edit. the r_n-s are in [0,1], didnt see that haha.
It doesnt matter, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot sangchul Lee!

Comment: If $r_n \in [0, 1]$ then the computation will be slightly easier, but I guess you are right. It really shouldn't matter. :)